# Moralis.Auth.verify 400 bad request error

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, authorization, moralis

I'm following the moralis tutorial to build an authentication and authorization system with moralis and reactJS https://docs.moralis.io/authentication-api/evm/how-to-authenticate-users-with-metamask-using-react. I get this error when i hit this route `http://localhost:4000/verify`. The code that creates this error is the following:

```
const { address, profileId } = (
      await Moralis.Auth.verify({
        message,
        signature,
        networkType: "evm",
      })
    ).raw;
```

This is the full code of the request:

```
const Moralis = require("moralis").default;

const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

// to use our .env variables
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
const port = 4000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// allow access to React app domain
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  })
);

const config = {
  domain: process.env.APP_DOMAIN,
  statement: "Please sign this message to confirm your identity.",
  uri: process.env.REACT_URL,
  timeout: 60,
};

app.post("/verify", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { message, signature } = req.body;

    const { address, profileId } = (
      await Moralis.Auth.verify({
        message,
        signature,
        networkType: "evm",
      })
    ).raw;

    const user = { address, profileId, signature };

    // create JWT token
    const token = jwt.sign(user, process.env.AUTH_SECRET);

    // set JWT cookie
    res.cookie("jwt", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
    });

    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

If you have any suggestion please let me know it.